# Extracting company name and other information inside all urls present in a webpage using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
<li>
    <strong>Company Name</strong> 
    ":" 
    <span itemprop="name">PT ERA MURNI BUSANA</span>
</li>
```

In the above HTML code, I am trying to extract the company name which is PT ERA MURNI BUSANA.
if I use a single test link, I can get the name using the single line code I wrote:

```
soup.find_all("span",attrs={"itemprop":"name"})[3].get_text()
```

But I want to extract the information from all such pages present in a single web page.
So I write the for loop but it is fetch the details. I am pasting the part of the code that I have been trying which needs some modification.
Code:-

```
   for link in supplierlinks:     #links have been extracted and merged with the base url
       r=requests.get(link,headers=headers)
       soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
       companyname=soup.find_all("span",attrs={"itemprop":"name"})[2].get_text()
```

Output looks like:

{'Company Name': 'AIRINDO SAKTI GARMENT PT'}

{'Company Name': 'Garments'}

{'Company Name': 'Garments'}

Instead of the garments popping up in the output, I need the company name. How do I modify the code within for loop?

Link:https://idn.bizdirlib.com/node/5290

Comment: The code looks fine. You might have to check the soup by adding print statement and check whether it has name and the location of the same in response.

Comment: @Afrodille Pls check out my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can select sibling element to element `<strong>` that contains the text `"Company Name"` (also, don't forget to set User-Agent http header):

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://idn.bizdirlib.com/node/5290'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

print( soup.select_one('strong:contains("Company Name") + *').text )
```

Prints:

```
PT ERA MURNI BUSANA
```

---

EDIT: To get contact person:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://idn.bizdirlib.com/node/5290'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

print( soup.select_one('strong:contains("Company Name") + *').text )
print( soup.select_one('strong:contains("Contact") + *').text )
```

Prints:

```
PT ERA MURNI BUSANA
Mr.  Yohan  Kustanto
```

Comment: Can you explain this part of the code : " 'strong:contains("Company Name") + *' "?. I am unaware of the select_one method. Specifically what does the "+ *" indicate?

Comment: @Afrodille It will select first sibling to tag `<strong>`. The tag `<strong>` must contain text "Company Name". It's CSS selector: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Thanx a lot. How about the "+* " at the end?

Comment: @Afrodille The `+` will select elements that are placed immediately after some element. For example `div + p` selects all `<p>` elements that are placed immediately after `<div>` elements

Comment: When I try to extract the contact as mentioned in the link(question above) using the line of code:     contact_person=soup.select_one('strong:contains("Contact")+ *').text 
it throws an error:AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' .

Comment: @Afrodille I updated my answer. Did you set correct HTTP headers in request? Otherwise the server returns incorrect response.

Comment: headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}                   I am using google chrome. So I think this header should be alright?

Comment: @Afrodille Try to `print(soup)` and make sure the contact is there.

Comment: I checked the google chrome version(mine is 85.0.4183.102 ) and updated the headers to see if that could have any problem. But the error remains the same when I use : print( soup.select_one('strong:contains("Contact") + *').text )

while the second code that I tried :     contact=soup.find("span",attrs={"itemprop": "contactPoint"})
it gives the output :

{'Company Name': 'AIRINDO SAKTI GARMENT PT', 'Country': 'INDONESIA', 'Address': 'Kp Warung Ceuri RT 011/05 CICURUG', 'Contact Person': None}
           
So, I am getting the Contact person as "None".

Comment: @Afrodille If you search this URL, https://idn.bizdirlib.com/node/22631 <- It doesn't have Contact

Comment: Yes. You are right. So it has to be handled through error handling like try and except?

Comment: @Afrodille Yes, you can handle it with `try..except` and in `except` part assign, for example `contact = 'not found'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0'}

r = requests.get('https://idn.bizdirlib.com/node/5290',headers=headers).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'html5lib')

print(soup.find_all("span",attrs={"itemprop":"name"})[-1].get_text())

div = soup.find('div',class_ = "content clearfix")

li_tags = div.div.find_all('fieldset')[1].find_all('div')[-1].ul.find_all('li')

supplierlinks = []

for li in li_tags:
    try:
        supplierlinks.append("https://idn.bizdirlib.com/"+li.a['href'])
    except:
        pass

for link in supplierlinks:
    r = requests.get(link,headers=headers).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'html5lib')
    print(soup.find_all("span", attrs={"itemprop": "name"})[-1].get_text())
```

Output:

```
PT ERA MURNI BUSANA
PT ELKA SURYA ABADI
PT EMPANG BESAR MAKMUR
PT EMS
PT ENERON
PT ENPE JAYA
PT ERIDANI TOUR AND TRAVEL
PT EURO ASIA TRADE & INDUSTRY
PT EUROKARS CHRISDECO UTAMA
PT EVERAGE VALVES METAL
PT EVICO
```

This code prints the company names of all the links on the page

Comment: Thanx a lot. It works. I have one problem while extracting contact person. It shows list index out of range. Code:-soup.find_all("span", attrs={"itemprop": "contactPoint"})[-1].get_text() .For the single test link it works though, but not inside the loop.